# File format need for inverted indexing

Tags: file, indexing, format, inverted-index

i have been working on Inverted indexing, which index documents collection, store each term with information and also store its reference in posting file (document id, location, etc.).

Currently i store it in .txt file format which need string matching for each and every query concerning to that .txt file, which take more time and also something more complex.

Now i want to store that information in a file like linked list style data structure. so is this possible for this type of scenario.... (and also i am using PHP language for indexing).

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The point of an inverted index is to allow for extremely fast access to the list of occurrences (the postings list) for any given term. If you want to implement it using simple, readily-available data structures, then the best you can probably do is

- Use a hash to store the mapping from terms to postings lists
- Store each postings list as a continuous block of sorted integers (i.e. something like `ArrayList` in Java or `std::vector` in C++). Do not use a linked list because that involves a huge amount of space wasted for pointers

A more proper (and more sophisticated) implementation would take into account:

- That postings lists can get *very* large, so you would have to break it up into multiple chunks, each stored as one continuous block
- That postings lists can and should be compressed

Detailed descriptions of these techniques are found in the classical book [Managing Gigabytes](http://www.librarything.com/work/84105/covers/).

Comment: actually, currently my data is store in .txt file, when i retrieve the data need the text matching. So basically i want to know how to reduce that matching processing and get directly a term or posting list information....Thanks.